# How to make winform window transparent and picture Visible?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a idea for designed window in winform. like below. I try the window opacity propriety.

But the Image also not visible. How to make this in winform.

[image]

I found this image in google. Thanks.

Comment: Looks transparent to me. What's the problem?

Comment: @Cody: It's an image not a real project by Sagotharan...

Comment: It looks like the designer is in the background, with the application actually running in the foreground. I guess it's really impossible to say considering the question doesn't provide many details. They lied when they told you that an image was worth 1000 words. Code is, though. Don't see any of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [Form.TransparencyKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx)  property

Make sure the background of the picture you use have the a certain color and set this color as the TransparencyKey.

You should also set the [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx)  property to FormBorderStyle.None in order hide the form's title, border, etc:

Answer (score 1):

The [transparent borderless forms in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/XparentFormsCS10282007212944PM/XparentFormsCS.aspx) article on C# Corner describes precisely what you are looking for. A simple search on Google [c#, borderless, transparant, window, form] did the job.

[image]